# Javascript parseInt error on IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

The below code doesn't work on `IE`, could anyone help me?

```
onclick="x.value=parseInt(b.value*d.value*c.value)+parseInt(a.value)
```

On all other browsers, it seems to be fine and doing the calculation and giving the output but on IE no matter what I do, the output stays as `0` value, below is my whole form for targeting the issue better :

```
<form id="mainselection">
        <h6>Transfer Fee Calculator</h6>    
<select name="a">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="0">Dalaman</option>
    <option value="30">Bodrum</option>
</select>
<select name="b">
    <option value="0">Resort</option>
    <option value="10">Marmaris</option>
    <option value="12">Icmeler</option>
    <option value="18">Turunc</option>
</select>
<select name="c">
    <option value="0">Pax</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>  
</select>
<select name="d">
    <option value="1">One Way</option>
    <option value="2">Return</option>
</select>
<br />
<span class="total">Total:</span><output name="x" for="a b c ">0</output>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="currency">£</span>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Calculate" class="cal-but" onclick="x.value=parseInt(b.value*d.value*c.value)+parseInt(a.value)">
<input type="button" value="Book Now" class="book" onclick="window.location='reservation.html'">
```

Comment: Don't use intrusive Javascript, besides browser errors.

Comment: Are you checking for errors?

Comment: There are too many `&nbsp;` if you learn how margins and padding work it will surely work like magic!

Comment: Did you try: `onclick="javascript:'x.value=parseInt(b.value*d.value*c.value)+parseInt(a.value)';`

Comment: yes i tried onclick="javascript:'x.value=parseInt(b.value*d.value*c.value)+parseInt(a.value‌​)'; that doesnt work on none of the browsers

Comment: adeneo, problem has got nothing to do with css + if you can give margin to a span element after <output>, i am gonna kill myself

Comment: `parseInt()` should always be given its second parameter. eg `parseInt(a.value,10)`. Without this, it can sometimes default to the wrong number base and give you the wrong figure. (this isn't likely to be the problem for you in this case, as it would be the same across all browsers, but you should make sure you do that every time you use `parseInt`; it's one of javascript's more annoying quirks)

Comment: agreed with @adeneo about losing the `&nbsp` characters and replacing them with a margin or a padding. Yes, you can do it. Padding is probably the one you want.

Comment: @javapirate: that's invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to say is that this is *not* an IE bug. It's to do with you using non-standard ways of accessing element names in your Javascript code.

The problem you have is that you're using the elements' `name` attribute as global Javascript variables. This is not (and never has been) a recommended practice. Some browsers support it for backward-compatibility reasons, but that doesn't mean it'll continue working in future versions of any browser. It isn't standard and shouldn't be used.

The correct way to access individual elements directly in Javascript is by using the `getElementsById()` method. This will give you good cross-browser compatibility that your current code does not have.

**The solution:**

- Step 1: Add an `id='x'` next to your `name='x'`. And do the same for any other elements that you're currently accessing by name
- Step 2: Wherever you're using variables like `x` that are for names of elements, replace the variable name with `document.getElementById('x')`.

  Yes, it's a lot more long-winded, but that is the correct way to do it.

That will solve the problem for you.